# While navigating from 1st page to 2nd page, 1st page (textbox text) gets removed in windows phone C# wpf

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I am having multiple textbox in page 1, after i fill the textbox i click next button to navigate to page 2,for navigation i used this way,
"this.Navigationservice.Navigate(new Uri("page2.xaml"),Urikind.Relative))",it navigates to page2, after i fill the page 2 and press done button , it navigates to previous page(i.e., page1),in done click i followed the same way for navigation to "this.Naviagtionserice.navigate(new uri("page1.xaml"),Urikind.Relative)),it return back to page 1, **but in page 1, entered textbox text fields gets erased only empty textbox showing without entered content in it** how can i achieve this task? pls suggest me..

Regards,
Lokesh.J

Answer (score 0):

To return to the previous page, use:

```
NavigationService.GoBack();
```

`NavigationService.Navigate` will create a new instance of the page (thus displaying a new empty textbox). `Navigation.GoBack` will restore the previous page.

Comment: Navigationservice.GoBack() restoring my previous page, but i want to read the textbox content of page 2 to page 1, for achieving this i used this way,texbox_manipulation started in page 2 with,  string dt = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Cal.SelectedDate);
                string urlofdestinationpage = "/page1.xaml";
                urlofdestinationpage += string.Format("?TextData=" + dt.ToString());this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(urlofdestinationpage, UriKind.Relative)); e.Complete();

Comment: e.Handled = true;  in page 1 i follow this way, protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        { IDictionary<string, string> x = this.NavigationContext.QueryString;  String a = Convert.ToString(x["TextData"]); txtsecretquestion.Text = a.ToString();base.OnNavigatedTo(e);with the help of NavigationService.GoBack(), i want to read the page 2 textbox content to page1 textbox, how it is possible, else how can i achieve this task suggest me

Comment: @lokesh You can just create a static property somewhere and store the value there. Or consider refactoring your application to use MVVM.

Comment: A quick and dirty way to do it: Add a static property in your Page2.xaml.cs: `public static string TextBox2Text { get; set; }`, then fill it when leaving the page : `TextBox2Text = TextBox2.Text;`. Then you can just read it from anywhere in the application: `MessageBox.Show(Page2.TextBox2Text);`